# Namespace not found in view, works in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, namespaces, exchangewebservices

I'm working with Microsoft Exchange Web Services and for whatever reason I cannot access the namespace in my views, but it works fine in my controller code.

My controller code:

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace EWS.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var service = new ExchangeService();
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password");
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("username", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            var userMailbox = new Mailbox("emailAddress");
            var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, userMailbox);

            var itemView = new ItemView(20);   // page size
            var userItems = service.FindItems(folderId, itemView);

            return View(userItems.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

My controller code works as expected, pulling in 20 of the latest users emails. However, when I want to display these emails in a View I get the following error:

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Data' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices'
```

In my View, I've tried adding:

```
@using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
```

which results in the same error. I've also tried adding the namespace to the Web.Config file in my Views folder:

```
<add namespace="Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data"/>
```

and again, we get the same error.

I've never ran into the issue before where my controller can find a namespace, but my view could not. The fact that my controller can find the namespace tells me that my references are correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried? ``@{ using Microsoft.Exchange.WebService.Data; }``

Comment: What type does `service.FindItems` return?

Comment: The model passed to the view is of type `List<Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item>`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - that notation makes no difference, still can't find the namespace in the view.

Comment: I should note that Visual Studio intellisense recognizes Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Auth in my view, but none of the other namespaces such as AutoDiscover, Data, or DNS as my controller does.

Comment: I'm assuming you've already tried the basic debugging stuff? Clean and rebuild your solution, close Visual Studio completely and reopen it, etc.

Comment: I've had to close and reopen visual studio to pick up web.config namespace additions, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I've tried rebuilding, opening/closing visual studio, etc. Again, this is not an intellisense issue, when the View is compiled when I hit the page I get the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing all Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices references, and re-installing them via Nuget and cleaning my solution.

Not sure why this happened or how it could even happen, but that seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've got a typo in your view:

```
@using Microsoft.Exchange.WebService.Data
```

which should be:

```
@using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data
```

Also you indicated that you have added the namespace to your `~/Views/web.config` which seems correct, just don't forget to close and reopen your Razor view for Visual Studio Intellisense to pick the change, otherwise it should work fine if you run it.

Comment: This was a typo in my original post, I was indeed adding the correct version.

Comment: Also, this is not really a problem with intellisense picking it up. Not only does intellisense not pick up the namespace I'm looking for in my View, it also bombs out with the error in the original post.